# LiveData observation won't update

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I want to send some data to the server and show its response to the user.
I'm using MVVM so I created a repository like this:

```
class Repository {


    fun getData(context: Context, word: String): LiveData<String> {

        val result = MutableLiveData<String>()

        val request = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST,
            "https://.......",
            Response.Listener {

                result.value = it.toString()


            },
            Response.ErrorListener {

                result.value = it.toString()

            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["word"] = word
                return params

            }

        }

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        queue.add(request)

        return result


    }


}
```

which just sends 'word' to the server and get its response.
my view model class contains just a mutableLiveData and a function. it is like this:

```
class ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


    var result = MutableLiveData<String>()


    fun getData(word: String): LiveData<String> {
        val repository = Repository()
        result = repository.getData(getApplication(), word) as MutableLiveData<String>
        return result
    }


}
```

I set an observation for result in my main Activity, therefore it is my MainActivity codes:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)


submit.setOnClickListener {
    model.getData(search_txt.text.toString())

}

model.result.observe(this, Observer {
    Log.i("Log", "observe is :$it")
    text.text = it
})
}
```

but it doesn't work! I get the user's input using an edit text and after pressing a button, I call getData function which is in my View Model class. but it returns always null and observation won't work.

I try to put observe the method in my button listener, in this way I get the result but it seems it's not a correct way because after I rotate my phone, all data ware gone and I need to fetch data from the server again while it shouldn't.

Comment: Why are you creating new `MutableLiveData` instances all the time in your repository? And why does your `ViewModel` need to have a  `MutableLiveData` instance of its own?

Comment: what should I do instead? @Michael

Comment: Have a `MutableLiveData` instance that belongs to the `Repository` instance, and then `Repository.getData` can call `setValue` or `postValue` on it. All `ViewModel.getData` needs to do is `return repository.getData()` (the `Repository` instance should belong to the `ViewModel` instance rather being local to `getData`).

Comment: oh, thanks, I guess finally I can work with live data and MVVM, you saved my time.@Michael